# grub: Booting Ubuntu off /boot in LVM, broken after upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, grub

I have servers I want to upgrade remotely and headlessly from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS.  This upgrade has to happen via script, with no interaction.

The `do-release-upgrade` command exits cleanly, however after rebooting the machine ends up at the grub rescue prompt with `error: file not found`.

My `/boot` is in LVM (I guess I shouldn't have done that; too late to fix that now).  Is this why grub can't find it?  I can see the logical volumes when I `ls` from the rescue prompt.  Attempting to `ls (lv-root)` results in `bad file name`.

`/boot` resides on a logical volume for `/`:

```
   --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/lv/root
  VG Name                lv
  LV UUID                blah-blah-blah
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                9.31 GiB
  Current LE             2384
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0
```

I tried `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` after the upgrade, before rebooting, but that did not help.

I'm going from grub 1.99-21ubuntu3.14 to 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.

Boot-Repair etc. are out of the question since I will not have physical or network access to the server during this process.  The upgrade process must occur unattended, and after-the-fact rescue is not an option.

What do I need to do before/after `do-release-upgrade` to configure grub to boot properly?